# How does one automate Let’s Encrypt certificate renewal for Lighttpd?

Tags: raspberry-pi, lighttpd, lets-encrypt

On a Linux system running Lighttpd, how can I automate certificate renewal for Let’s Encrypt certs. Let’s Encrypt provides great scripts for Apache 2 and NGINX but not Lighttpd which is much more comfortable for small systems like Raspberry Pi or old boxes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Danny Tuppeny provides a great start with a simple script you can run on his blog posting [Installing Lighttpd, PHP 7 and LetsEncrypt on a Raspberry Pi (Raspbian Jessie Lite)](http://blog.dantup.com/2016/03/installing-lighttpd-php7-and-letsencrypt-on-raspberry-pi-raspbian-jessie-lite/)

```
# Renew cert
# updated for name change [mscalora]
letsencrypt-auto renew

# Rebuild the cert
pushd /etc/letsencrypt/live/<your-domain-here>/
cat privkey.pem cert.pem > combined.pem
popd

# Reload
/etc/init.d/lighttpd force-reload
```

A more generalized version based on the latest Let’s Encrypt script package can be found in my Gist: [letsencrypt-update-lighttpd](https://gist.github.com/mscalora/94f384d1311f66ac09ea6d31d77a102e). This script will handle multiple domains with certificates.

Danny Tuppeny's blog post has info about the original setup too.

Answer (score 2):

There is a universal [standalone](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#standalone) authenticator(plugin) that fits to any web server. However in case your server handles the requests on port 80 you will face an issue that certbots says *"This plugin needs to bind to port 80 in order to perform domain validation, so you may need to stop your existing webserver."* So, in case you have to renew certificate for the webserver it gets downtime for the period of domain validation.
If you don't care regarding such downtime use standalone plugin as is.

But, there is a solution that can help you to avoid downtime:

1. Run [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) with parameters: --standalone --http-01-port 123456 - the plugin's webserver will be launched on port 12346 instead of 80, so you won't need to stop your webserver.
2. Set up and run an intermediate very lightweight  reverse proxy for instance [Tinyproxy](http://tinyproxy.github.io/):

yum -y install tinyproxy --enablerepo='epel';

Configure it listening to port 12345. Its config can look like:

```
User tinyproxy
Group tinyproxy

Port 12345
Timeout 6000
MaxClients 100
MinSpareServers 5
MaxSpareServers 20
StartServers 10
MaxRequestsPerChild 0
BindSame yes
DisableViaHeader Yes
ConnectPort 80
ConnectPort 12346
AddHeader "X-Forwarded-Proto" "http"
ReversePath "/" "http://127.0.0.1/"
ReversePath "/.well-known/acme-challenge/" "http://127.0.0.1:12346/.well-known/acme-challenge/"
ReverseOnly Yes
ReverseMagic Yes
```

It should listen to HTTP traffic and redirect requests between two webservers. Proxy filters traffic and redirects a Let's Ecnrypt validation request, that contains '/.well-known/acme-challenge/', to the plugin's webserver to port 12346 and regular HTTP requests to your webserver to port 80.

3. Create HTTP traffic redirection to reverse proxy from port 80 to port 12345 with iptables and accept traffic on new ports:

iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 12346 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 12345 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp ! -s 127.0.0.1/32 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 12345

4. Right after validation is complete remove mentioned above firewall rules and stop the proxy server.

That's all you got an automatic Let's Encrypt certificate renewal with no downtime and no changes of your webserver content.

You may download the script [generate-ssl-cert.sh](https://github.com/jelastic-jps/lets-encrypt/blob/master/scripts/generate-ssl-cert.sh) where the solution is implemented  and adopt it to your needs. Actually this script is a part of automation package known as [Let's Encrypt SSL Add-On](https://github.com/jelastic-jps/lets-encrypt). The package is a [Cloud Scripting](https://docs.cloudscripting.com/) scenario.